# Optimise plotting process of a large matrix

Tags: matlab

I have two 2x40401 matrices x1 and x2.

Algorithm:

- read first component of kth column of x1, x1(1, k).
- if x1(1, k) > 0 plot kth column of x2, x2(:, k) as a red dot.
- if x1(1, k) < 0 plot kth column of x2, x2(:, k) as an blue dot.

The process I'm using now is

```
for k = 1:40401
    if x1(1, k) < 0
        plot(x2(1, k), x2(2, k), 'r.')
    elseif x1(1, k) > 0
        plot(x2(1, k), x2(2, k), 'b.')
    end
end
```

Now my question is, is there any way to do this more efficiently? Since these matrices are fairly large these takes a while to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can vectorize the plot as follows:

```
% Find all indices where x1 row 1 is less than 0. 
% a new variable y is not necessary but it makes code more readable.
y = x1(1,:) < 0;
% Plot all x2 points where x1(1,:) < 0
plot(x2(1,(y==1)),x2(2,(y==1)),'r.');
% Plot all x2 points where x1(1,:) > 0
plot(x2(1,(y==0)),x2(2,(y==0)),'b.');
```